# Fixing water damaged flooring

Tags: wood, flooring, water-damage

The corner of my study area was exposed to water damage due to clogged gutter leaking water directly on the foundation around the corner. What steps should I take to fix this? I already cleared the block in the gutter and water is no longer dropping there anymore. I have spare boards from when the house was built. I am guessing first step is the clean the mold/mildew from the drywall and floor?

[image: chopstick for comparison]

Comment: Is that hardwood?

Comment: It's engineered wood

Comment: Then yes, your first step is cleanup.